# Which scheduler should I use to decode a bitmap

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, rx-android, bitmapfactory

I've noticed that loading of bitmap in my appplication takes a lot of time, causing lags in animation if it is run on the main thread, so I moved it to a background thread.

```
val scheduler = ...
Observable.fromCallable {
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, resourceId)
}.subscribeOn(scheduler)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe {bitmap ->
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
}
```

However, there are several schedulers to choose from. On the one hand the bitmap is loaded from disk, so it should be `Schedulers.io()`, but on the other hand it is also computation intensive, so `Schedulers.computation()` is another candidate. The bitmap has size of about 1 megapixel, and takes about 50 milliseconds to load.

So how can I decide, which scheduler to choose for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say `Schedulers.io()`, as loading the resource is a blocking operation, and in [Schedulers](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/schedulers/Schedulers.html#computation--) it states that for `Schedulers.computation()`:

> If the `RxJavaPlugins.setFailOnNonBlockingScheduler(boolean)` is set to `true`, attempting to execute operators that block while running on this scheduler will throw an `IllegalStateException`."